# What is the most secure way to set keystore path and password in java web project?

Tags: java, security, jboss, wildfly, keystore

I have a Java Web Project that runs on wildfly 10. I had to use ldaps for the authentication and I needed to do it in the code directly. So I had to set the **keystore** path and password so **ldaps** would work. I have those lines clear in the code :

```
String keystorePath = System.getProperty("java.home") + "\\lib\\security\\jssecacerts";
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keystorePath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");
```

I read a lot and saw a couple a ways to do it, but in every case I'll need to write the password somewhere.

I'm new in all this and I'm wondering what is the safest way to do it.

I thought about some options:

1. Keep it this way. Maybe it's safe enough?
2. Add it in the standalone.xml of the server (if that's the right file to modify) such as [this](https://docs.jboss.org/author/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=66322705) and hide the password using the [vault tool](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7SecuringPasswords)
3. Hash it and store it in the database. Maybe with [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/)?
4. Create a xml file in the project with that kind of information.

What would be the best way to do it? Is there any easy good way to do it I'm not aware of?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I was also looking for answer to this question; glad that you asked. Let's see if it gets answered here, and when!